# Как правильно добавить класс к тегу

Tags: javascript, jquery

В общем я переьираю массив и мне нужно добавить в тег - класс, затем в этот новый "классный" тег внутрь вставить значение массива.

чтобы было вот так

---

```
                <li class="go **1**" ><a>**1**</a></li>
                <li class="go **2**" ><a>**2**</a></li>
                <li class="go **3**" ><a>**3**</a></li>
                <li class="go **4**" ><a>**4**</a></li>
                <li class="go **5**" ><a>**5**</a></li>
```

---

можно ли как то вставить все теги а не только классы писать7

Спасибо.

```js
    for(var i=page-1;i<5; i ++) {
$(li.go).addClass(all_pages[i]);
$(li.go.all_pages[i]).text(all_pages[i]);
                    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function assignClassesAndTexts() {

  var all_pages = [
    "class1", "class2", "class3", "class4", "class5"
  ];

  var $liGo = $("li.go");
  for (var i = 0; i < $liGo.length; i++) {
    $liGo.eq(i).addClass(all_pages[i]).find("a").text(all_pages[i]);
  }

}
```

```css
.class1 { color: red; }
.class2 { color: green; }
.class3 { color: blue; }
.class4 { color: aqua; }
.class5 { color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="go **1**"><a>**1**</a></li>
  <li class="go **2**"><a>**2**</a></li>
  <li class="go **3**"><a>**3**</a></li>
  <li class="go **4**"><a>**4**</a></li>
  <li class="go **5**"><a>**5**</a></li>
</ul>

<button onclick="assignClassesAndTexts()">Click</button>
```

Comment: а что это такое eq(i)? ну и не работает блин код( И как бы не совсем понятно что как помещается в тег "а"  текст.

Comment: @dpi https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Заработало но с jquery 2.1.1 в чем там загвостка если будет 3.2.1 библиотека стоять?

Comment: @dpi Никакой загвоздки нет. Посмотрите, я изменил версию jQuery в примере.

Comment: Еще такой вопрос все работает, но только при повторной перезегрузке страници через F5 В чем может быть прикол??

Comment: @dpi Вы же понимаете, что я не вижу Ваш монитор? Что "все работает при повторной перезегрузке"? У меня в ответе все работает без перезагрузки.

Comment: перебор массива имеется в виду. Ну да ладно буду дебажить. И на этом спасибо.